# Convert cell to double value while reading from text file matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a data from a file but i can't change the format from cell to double, can any body help me in that.

the code which i wrote:

```
fid=fopen(filename); 
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline) 
   temp = strsplit(tline);% temp should be array holding double values.
end
```

Sample of the file(one row only):

```
0.0000000e+00   4.1800000e+01   4.4800000e+01   4.7100000e+01   3.7400000e+01   4.0100000e+01   4.0600000e+01   4.3800000e+01   4.3100000e+01   6.2800000e+01   6.3600000e+01   7.3900000e+01   7.3100000e+01   7.8500000e+01   7.0400000e+01   6.8700000e+01   5.9600000e+01   7.4000000e+01   6.5900000e+01   6.5300000e+01   6.0600000e+01   6.6600000e+01   5.5600000e+01   5.7900000e+01   5.5100000e+01   6.4800000e+01   6.7600000e+01   7.4500000e+01   5.9100000e+01   5.5200000e+01   5.3800000e+01   5.9900000e+01   5.0600000e+01   5.1500000e+01   6.1400000e+01   6.8900000e+01   5.9100000e+01   7.1000000e+01   6.1500000e+01   6.9900000e+01   7.5200000e+01   8.0600000e+01   7.4300000e+01   7.4700000e+01   6.3400000e+01   6.7300000e+01   7.3600000e+01   8.2200000e+01   6.9800000e+01   7.2600000e+01   7.6100000e+01  -1.0300000e+01  -5.9000000e+00  -3.3000000e+00  -1.4100000e+01  -1.1500000e+01  -9.5000000e+00  -8.6000000e+00  -3.6000000e+00   1.4400000e+01   1.8900000e+01   3.0600000e+01   3.0600000e+01   3.6000000e+01   2.2600000e+01   2.1300000e+01   1.3900000e+01   2.7400000e+01   2.0100000e+01   1.7300000e+01   9.5000000e+00   1.6100000e+01   4.4000000e+00   8.8000000e+00   7.9000000e+00   2.0300000e+01   1.7500000e+01   2.8000000e+01   1.2100000e+01   4.9000000e+00   1.3000000e+00   9.0000000e+00   7.0000000e+00   2.2000000e+00   1.2300000e+01   2.0900000e+01   1.2300000e+01   2.3500000e+01   1.3300000e+01   2.2400000e+01   2.2400000e+01   2.5800000e+01   2.2300000e+01   2.0200000e+01   1.1200000e+01   1.7400000e+01   2.0900000e+01   2.6200000e+01   1.2600000e+01   2.4000000e+01   2.6500000e+01   3.8100000e+01   2.5200000e+01   4.6000000e+01   2.3300000e+01   3.5900000e+01   2.3200000e+01   4.2600000e+01   3.2100000e+01   6.7600000e+01   5.5400000e+01   7.8800000e+01   6.6600000e+01   8.6600000e+01   5.8700000e+01   7.2800000e+01   4.8400000e+01   7.6500000e+01   5.3200000e+01   6.7200000e+01   4.1600000e+01   6.0700000e+01   3.5300000e+01   5.7300000e+01   4.3900000e+01   7.2400000e+01   5.3400000e+01   7.8600000e+01   4.6600000e+01   5.5400000e+01   3.5800000e+01   5.6100000e+01   4.1900000e+01   5.3200000e+01   4.8800000e+01   7.1400000e+01   4.9000000e+01   7.5400000e+01   4.8700000e+01   7.5700000e+01   5.9100000e+01   7.5000000e+01   5.6400000e+01   7.2200000e+01   4.8100000e+01   7.0800000e+01   5.5500000e+01   7.3500000e+01   4.5100000e+01   7.4100000e+01   6.4800000e+01   2.7900000e+01   2.0200000e+01   3.8100000e+01   1.9400000e+01   2.6700000e+01   1.6900000e+01   3.4900000e+01   3.0500000e+01   5.9300000e+01   5.4400000e+01   7.0200000e+01   6.0900000e+01   7.6600000e+01   5.1700000e+01   6.5400000e+01   4.6300000e+01   6.9800000e+01   4.8100000e+01   5.7800000e+01   3.7600000e+01   4.9200000e+01   2.7700000e+01   4.8100000e+01   4.2200000e+01   6.7300000e+01   4.7400000e+01   7.0000000e+01   4.2000000e+01   4.6900000e+01   3.3200000e+01   4.7800000e+01   3.7500000e+01   4.8400000e+01   4.6300000e+01   6.4500000e+01   4.5500000e+01   6.8300000e+01   4.5400000e+01   6.6700000e+01   5.3400000e+01   6.6300000e+01   5.0400000e+01   6.3800000e+01   4.6300000e+01   6.2900000e+01   5.0000000e+01   6.4300000e+01   4.0500000e+01   6.4700000e+01   6.3200000e+01   1.3200000e+01   1.3300000e+01   2.5800000e+01   2.3000000e+01   1.6900000e+01   6.3000000e+00   1.8600000e+01   2.6800000e+01   4.3900000e+01   5.4000000e+01   5.8500000e+01   5.2500000e+01   6.1200000e+01   5.0600000e+01   5.7000000e+01   4.4400000e+01   5.9500000e+01   4.2600000e+01   4.5200000e+01   3.2000000e+01   3.2000000e+01   2.2000000e+01   3.7200000e+01   4.4600000e+01   5.5000000e+01   3.9300000e+01   5.3100000e+01   3.8900000e+01   3.3200000e+01   3.8200000e+01   3.2200000e+01   3.6600000e+01   4.5000000e+01   4.6700000e+01   5.0800000e+01   4.1600000e+01   5.6900000e+01   4.1400000e+01   5.3400000e+01   5.1100000e+01   5.6700000e+01   4.4400000e+01   5.3600000e+01   4.9400000e+01   4.8900000e+01   5.2600000e+01   5.2900000e+01   3.7600000e+01   5.2400000e+01   7.6500000e+01   3.9000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   4.5000000e+00   7.2000000e+00   2.9000000e+00   1.1100000e+01   4.6000000e+00   1.5100000e+01   2.0700000e+01   2.7100000e+01   3.7700000e+01   4.1300000e+01   3.7000000e+01   4.4900000e+01   2.8500000e+01   2.2400000e+01   3.2700000e+01   2.9800000e+01   2.6600000e+01   2.7900000e+01   3.5300000e+01   2.5500000e+01   2.1800000e+01   2.3900000e+01   3.5300000e+01   2.7100000e+01   3.0300000e+01   2.5400000e+01   1.5000000e+01   2.7000000e+01   2.2600000e+01   1.6500000e+01   8.8000000e+00   3.4500000e+01   2.9400000e+01   1.7800000e+01   2.9200000e+01   2.6800000e+01   3.4500000e+01   3.9500000e+01   3.8000000e+01   4.6300000e+01   4.3500000e+01   3.1900000e+01   2.2700000e+01   3.5800000e+01   4.1100000e+01   3.2200000e+01   3.1700000e+01   3.1800000e+01   3.2000000e+00   6.1000000e+00   8.2000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   2.5000000e+00   7.7000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   9.7000000e+00   3.1700000e+01   3.2800000e+01   4.7100000e+01   4.7700000e+01   5.0200000e+01   4.3100000e+01   3.6900000e+01   2.7600000e+01   3.6300000e+01   3.1100000e+01   2.8000000e+01   2.2700000e+01   2.9600000e+01   2.0200000e+01   2.2300000e+01   1.9400000e+01   3.0900000e+01   2.7400000e+01   3.3600000e+01   2.3500000e+01   1.5200000e+01   1.3800000e+01   1.8700000e+01   1.8600000e+01   1.0200000e+01   2.3700000e+01   2.9000000e+01   2.0400000e+01   3.3200000e+01   2.7100000e+01   3.3600000e+01   3.6800000e+01   4.2800000e+01   4.0000000e+01   4.2200000e+01   2.8600000e+01   2.6900000e+01   3.5800000e+01   4.2100000e+01   2.9300000e+01   3.3600000e+01   3.3100000e+01  -5.8000000e+00  -3.5000000e+00   1.2000000e+00  -1.1000000e+01  -6.5000000e+00  -6.3000000e+00  -5.3000000e+00  -8.0000000e-01   2.5600000e+01   2.8300000e+01   4.2400000e+01   4.2100000e+01   4.8500000e+01   3.6500000e+01   3.3500000e+01   2.2400000e+01   3.4900000e+01   2.5900000e+01   2.3600000e+01   1.3800000e+01   2.1800000e+01   1.0400000e+01   1.7500000e+01   1.4400000e+01   2.7500000e+01   2.3300000e+01   3.2700000e+01   1.8500000e+01   1.2400000e+01   6.5000000e+00   1.5200000e+01   1.5200000e+01   8.8000000e+00   1.8000000e+01   2.6200000e+01   1.7600000e+01   2.9900000e+01   1.9900000e+01   3.1700000e+01   3.1300000e+01   3.4800000e+01   3.1200000e+01   3.4400000e+01   2.2000000e+01   2.5600000e+01   3.1500000e+01   3.5100000e+01   2.0600000e+01   3.1000000e+01   3.2200000e+01   4.9000000e+01   5.0300000e+01   5.9400000e+01   4.3700000e+01   4.8300000e+01   4.5800000e+01   5.3000000e+01   5.7800000e+01   8.6000000e+01   8.7500000e+01   1.0190000e+02   9.9400000e+01   1.0680000e+02   9.0600000e+01   9.3400000e+01   8.0400000e+01   9.5600000e+01   8.1100000e+01   8.1400000e+01   6.8300000e+01   7.8700000e+01   6.3700000e+01   7.5000000e+01   7.5700000e+01   9.1800000e+01   8.2000000e+01   9.3700000e+01   7.4600000e+01   7.2300000e+01   6.3700000e+01   7.3000000e+01   7.1900000e+01   7.1100000e+01   7.7800000e+01   8.7800000e+01   7.7100000e+01   9.0600000e+01   7.5600000e+01   9.2800000e+01   8.7500000e+01   9.1200000e+01   8.3600000e+01   8.9400000e+01   7.8000000e+01   8.4900000e+01   8.6700000e+01   9.2700000e+01   7.3800000e+01   9.1700000e+01   9.6200000e+01   5.9000000e+01   6.2100000e+01   6.7800000e+01   5.7600000e+01   5.8500000e+01   5.5800000e+01   6.2900000e+01   7.2000000e+01   9.6400000e+01   1.0200000e+02   1.1170000e+02   1.0970000e+02   1.1470000e+02   1.0170000e+02   1.0830000e+02   9.7600000e+01   1.0800000e+02   9.4200000e+01   8.9900000e+01   7.8900000e+01   8.2400000e+01   7.3200000e+01   8.3600000e+01   8.9900000e+01   1.0320000e+02   9.4800000e+01   1.0510000e+02   8.7500000e+01   8.3300000e+01   8.1300000e+01   8.3800000e+01   8.6400000e+01   8.5500000e+01   9.3000000e+01   9.9200000e+01   9.0100000e+01   1.0230000e+02   9.0400000e+01   1.0450000e+02   1.0050000e+02   1.0090000e+02   9.4900000e+01   9.9000000e+01   9.5400000e+01   9.9600000e+01   1.0040000e+02   1.0310000e+02   8.7900000e+01   1.0210000e+02   1.1200000e+02   1.0180000e+02   1.0620000e+02   1.1040000e+02   1.0650000e+02   1.0420000e+02   1.0040000e+02   1.0830000e+02   1.1810000e+02   1.3730000e+02   1.4840000e+02   1.5500000e+02   1.5220000e+02   1.5350000e+02   1.4400000e+02   1.5460000e+02   1.4530000e+02   1.5200000e+02   1.3890000e+02   1.3080000e+02   1.2370000e+02   1.1830000e+02   1.1320000e+02   1.2250000e+02   1.3550000e+02   1.4480000e+02   1.3540000e+02   1.4250000e+02   1.2930000e+02   1.2280000e+02   1.2510000e+02   1.2140000e+02   1.2790000e+02   1.2870000e+02   1.3660000e+02   1.3880000e+02   1.3330000e+02   1.4640000e+02   1.3430000e+02   1.4600000e+02   1.4430000e+02   1.4280000e+02   1.3490000e+02   1.3960000e+02   1.4320000e+02   1.4410000e+02   1.4450000e+02   1.4240000e+02   1.2970000e+02   1.4070000e+02   1.5850000e+02  -1.7100000e+01  -9.5000000e+00  -1.0000000e+01  -5.2000000e+00  -1.2200000e+01  -1.4000000e+01  -4.1000000e+00   1.7000000e+00   2.2400000e+01   2.5900000e+01   3.4700000e+01   3.3400000e+01   3.1500000e+01   1.9300000e+01   3.7100000e+01   2.5000000e+01   3.7300000e+01   2.4500000e+01   1.9500000e+01   9.9000000e+00  -3.3000000e+00  -3.7000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   1.7600000e+01   2.6900000e+01   1.3200000e+01   1.8700000e+01   1.1200000e+01   2.7000000e+00  -3.5000000e+00  -6.3000000e+00   1.8000000e+00   1.1300000e+01   9.6000000e+00   1.5800000e+01   1.2700000e+01   3.4700000e+01   1.0900000e+01   2.1400000e+01   2.7200000e+01   2.1400000e+01   1.0000000e+01   1.7300000e+01   2.6000000e+01   3.0700000e+01   2.6800000e+01   1.4400000e+01   6.8000000e+00   2.0000000e+01   3.6200000e+01  -9.1000000e+00  -8.0000000e-01  -1.9000000e+00  -5.4000000e+00  -6.1000000e+00   3.4000000e+00  -2.4000000e+00   2.3000000e+00   1.6000000e+01   1.8800000e+01   3.4200000e+01   3.9300000e+01   3.3800000e+01   3.3800000e+01   2.5800000e+01   2.1800000e+01   2.3500000e+01   2.2900000e+01   1.7200000e+01   2.2200000e+01   2.1400000e+01   1.6900000e+01   1.9000000e+01   1.5400000e+01   2.5000000e+01   2.3400000e+01   2.3100000e+01   1.8600000e+01   1.4900000e+01   1.3900000e+01   1.3300000e+01   1.6800000e+01   6.8000000e+00   2.5200000e+01   1.7800000e+01   1.2700000e+01   2.3500000e+01   2.4700000e+01   2.2600000e+01   1.8300000e+01   2.3700000e+01   4.4500000e+01   5.4000000e+01   3.1800000e+01   1.5900000e+01   2.1600000e+01   2.9500000e+01   2.5200000e+01   2.5700000e+01   2.4700000e+01  -3.5000000e+00   4.9000000e+00   4.2000000e+00  -3.5000000e+00  -1.8000000e+00   4.4000000e+00  -6.0000000e-01   9.9000000e+00   3.0500000e+01   3.5300000e+01   5.0900000e+01   5.5400000e+01   5.3300000e+01   4.9200000e+01   4.1400000e+01   3.2800000e+01   4.0300000e+01   3.6100000e+01   3.0600000e+01   2.6800000e+01   3.0500000e+01   2.2700000e+01   2.7000000e+01   2.4500000e+01   3.3000000e+01   2.9000000e+01   3.6200000e+01   2.9900000e+01   2.1200000e+01   1.3500000e+01   1.9500000e+01   2.7200000e+01   1.9200000e+01   2.8700000e+01   2.4800000e+01   2.5100000e+01   3.9000000e+01   3.4600000e+01   3.5400000e+01   2.6400000e+01   3.1600000e+01   4.7700000e+01   5.6400000e+01   4.0000000e+01   2.8800000e+01   3.5000000e+01   4.0300000e+01   3.3200000e+01   3.8300000e+01   3.0600000e+01   1.6900000e+01   2.4500000e+01   2.4500000e+01   1.3800000e+01   1.4700000e+01   1.8200000e+01   1.6100000e+01   2.7900000e+01   5.1300000e+01   5.7900000e+01   7.2000000e+01   7.5400000e+01   7.6100000e+01   6.9700000e+01   6.5300000e+01   5.5200000e+01   6.3000000e+01   5.5700000e+01   5.0300000e+01   4.5000000e+01   5.0300000e+01   4.0800000e+01   4.6800000e+01   4.6700000e+01   5.8300000e+01   5.3100000e+01   5.9900000e+01   5.0800000e+01   4.2200000e+01   3.5000000e+01   4.1700000e+01   4.8000000e+01   3.9100000e+01   4.7800000e+01   5.1600000e+01   4.7300000e+01   5.8400000e+01   5.0000000e+01   6.0700000e+01   5.5200000e+01   5.3700000e+01   6.0200000e+01   6.6600000e+01   5.7000000e+01   5.3000000e+01   5.7300000e+01   6.2200000e+01   5.1900000e+01   5.9600000e+01   5.7300000e+01   1.3900000e+01   2.1000000e+01   2.2500000e+01   9.9000000e+00   1.1000000e+01   1.2600000e+01   1.3000000e+01   2.6600000e+01   5.2500000e+01   5.8600000e+01   7.0800000e+01   7.1600000e+01   7.4400000e+01   6.6000000e+01   6.5800000e+01   5.5600000e+01   6.1900000e+01   5.2400000e+01   4.5200000e+01   3.7500000e+01   4.5200000e+01   3.4100000e+01   4.3300000e+01   4.6400000e+01   5.9700000e+01   5.1500000e+01   5.8500000e+01   4.6900000e+01   4.1000000e+01   3.2800000e+01   4.0100000e+01   4.5800000e+01   3.8100000e+01   4.4300000e+01   5.1600000e+01   4.5700000e+01   5.4900000e+01   4.5200000e+01   6.0600000e+01   5.7600000e+01   5.2500000e+01   5.2400000e+01   5.8200000e+01   5.2600000e+01   5.2300000e+01   5.5800000e+01   6.1500000e+01   4.7400000e+01   5.7600000e+01   6.1200000e+01  -9.0000000e-01   6.7000000e+00   6.2000000e+00  -3.5000000e+00  -3.2000000e+00  -2.6000000e+00  -9.0000000e-01   1.4000000e+01   3.5900000e+01   4.5700000e+01   5.4600000e+01   5.3300000e+01   5.3900000e+01   4.7600000e+01   5.3000000e+01   4.5000000e+01   4.7100000e+01   3.7500000e+01   2.8500000e+01   2.0900000e+01   2.3600000e+01   1.5500000e+01   2.3600000e+01   3.0800000e+01   4.2300000e+01   3.6100000e+01   4.3500000e+01   3.0200000e+01   2.3200000e+01   1.9200000e+01   2.3800000e+01   2.8600000e+01   2.1300000e+01   3.0800000e+01   3.6600000e+01   3.1200000e+01   3.8500000e+01   3.0200000e+01   4.3900000e+01   3.8500000e+01   3.5200000e+01   3.5400000e+01   3.9000000e+01   3.8500000e+01   3.7700000e+01   4.0100000e+01   4.3500000e+01   3.0300000e+01   3.9800000e+01   4.6600000e+01  -4.6000000e+00   8.0000000e-01  -2.0000000e-01  -5.9000000e+00  -5.5000000e+00  -7.4000000e+00  -4.9000000e+00   9.7000000e+00   2.8300000e+01   4.1400000e+01   4.8500000e+01   4.6800000e+01   4.5300000e+01   3.9200000e+01   4.8400000e+01   4.1500000e+01   4.3200000e+01   3.2700000e+01   2.2200000e+01   1.4800000e+01   1.1700000e+01   5.9000000e+00   1.5600000e+01   2.6000000e+01   3.5400000e+01   3.0300000e+01   3.6700000e+01   2.2000000e+01   1.6700000e+01   1.7500000e+01   1.6400000e+01   2.1800000e+01   1.5100000e+01   2.6700000e+01   3.2300000e+01   2.9300000e+01   3.5800000e+01   3.0700000e+01   4.0800000e+01   3.4500000e+01   3.1000000e+01   3.1200000e+01   3.4100000e+01   3.6400000e+01   3.7500000e+01   3.7900000e+01   3.7300000e+01   2.4100000e+01   3.3800000e+01   4.3500000e+01   4.0000000e-01   7.3000000e+00   9.6000000e+00   9.5000000e+00   4.2000000e+00   4.8000000e+00   3.3000000e+00   1.8500000e+01   3.2600000e+01   5.0900000e+01   5.8400000e+01   5.6700000e+01   4.8400000e+01   4.1600000e+01   4.9500000e+01   5.0200000e+01   5.1900000e+01   4.7300000e+01   3.4700000e+01   2.8700000e+01   1.5400000e+01   1.0100000e+01   2.3500000e+01   3.5900000e+01   4.4300000e+01   4.4000000e+01   4.5200000e+01   3.0500000e+01   2.5900000e+01   2.9100000e+01   2.1300000e+01   2.7700000e+01   1.9300000e+01   3.3500000e+01   4.2000000e+01   4.2300000e+01   4.1200000e+01   4.3300000e+01   4.7900000e+01   4.2000000e+01   3.5600000e+01   4.2900000e+01   4.3600000e+01   5.1400000e+01   5.0600000e+01   4.9100000e+01   4.3000000e+01   3.2600000e+01   3.8300000e+01   4.8100000e+01   3.6900000e+01   4.7700000e+01   4.5100000e+01   3.7500000e+01   3.7800000e+01   4.7100000e+01   3.8500000e+01   4.7400000e+01   6.5100000e+01   6.5100000e+01   8.2400000e+01   8.7100000e+01   8.3400000e+01   8.2500000e+01   7.8100000e+01   6.7000000e+01   7.0300000e+01   6.9100000e+01   6.3900000e+01   6.4400000e+01   6.3100000e+01   5.5600000e+01   6.5800000e+01   5.5600000e+01   6.7300000e+01   6.7800000e+01   6.6700000e+01   6.2700000e+01   5.8400000e+01   5.1500000e+01   5.2500000e+01   6.0700000e+01   5.2800000e+01   6.6500000e+01   5.8100000e+01   5.4700000e+01   6.6600000e+01   6.8500000e+01   6.6200000e+01   5.2600000e+01   6.1600000e+01   8.5800000e+01   9.6100000e+01   7.7600000e+01   6.0600000e+01   5.8300000e+01   6.6000000e+01   6.7700000e+01   6.6700000e+01   6.0400000e+01   1.0100000e+01   1.6400000e+01   1.8900000e+01   7.8000000e+00   1.2400000e+01   1.3400000e+01   1.1600000e+01   2.0700000e+01   4.3800000e+01   4.2000000e+01   6.2500000e+01   6.2900000e+01   6.5700000e+01   5.8400000e+01   5.5600000e+01   4.0200000e+01   5.1200000e+01   4.5600000e+01   4.4500000e+01   3.8700000e+01   4.2400000e+01   2.8400000e+01   3.8600000e+01   2.9900000e+01   4.4900000e+01   3.9700000e+01   4.6300000e+01   3.7800000e+01   3.4900000e+01   2.1400000e+01   2.9900000e+01   3.6500000e+01   3.1700000e+01   3.8100000e+01   3.4600000e+01   3.0800000e+01   4.9800000e+01   4.6400000e+01   4.7500000e+01   2.5100000e+01   3.7300000e+01   5.8100000e+01   7.4200000e+01   5.5700000e+01   4.1100000e+01   3.7700000e+01   5.0300000e+01   4.4200000e+01   4.8700000e+01   3.5600000e+01   2.4500000e+01   3.2300000e+01   3.4100000e+01   2.0800000e+01   2.2800000e+01   2.4100000e+01   2.2900000e+01   3.4800000e+01   5.9900000e+01   6.1900000e+01   8.0200000e+01   7.9200000e+01   8.2300000e+01   7.6000000e+01   7.6000000e+01   6.1100000e+01   6.9000000e+01   6.1100000e+01   5.8200000e+01   4.9700000e+01   5.4900000e+01   4.2400000e+01   5.4900000e+01   5.1100000e+01   6.4900000e+01   5.9800000e+01   6.6300000e+01   5.5500000e+01   5.2700000e+01   4.1300000e+01   4.9700000e+01   5.4300000e+01   4.9200000e+01   5.2700000e+01   5.7300000e+01   5.1000000e+01   6.4000000e+01   5.8100000e+01   6.9300000e+01   5.3500000e+01   5.5300000e+01   6.5500000e+01   7.9200000e+01   6.9800000e+01   6.3800000e+01   5.9800000e+01   6.9400000e+01   6.1100000e+01   6.6500000e+01   5.6600000e+01   3.4600000e+01   4.1700000e+01   4.3800000e+01   2.8500000e+01   3.0600000e+01   2.8700000e+01   3.0900000e+01   4.4200000e+01   7.0500000e+01   7.6200000e+01   8.9900000e+01   8.7300000e+01   8.9800000e+01   8.4300000e+01   8.8200000e+01   7.4900000e+01   7.8800000e+01   6.6900000e+01   6.0500000e+01   5.2900000e+01   5.9100000e+01   4.7900000e+01   5.9200000e+01   6.0600000e+01   7.4100000e+01   6.4400000e+01   7.2600000e+01   5.9900000e+01   5.7100000e+01   4.5800000e+01   5.6300000e+01   6.0300000e+01   5.3100000e+01   5.7300000e+01   6.4500000e+01   5.6400000e+01   6.7500000e+01   5.8500000e+01   7.6200000e+01   6.4700000e+01   6.3300000e+01   6.6100000e+01   7.6700000e+01   7.0500000e+01   6.7100000e+01   6.5600000e+01   7.3600000e+01   6.3300000e+01   7.2300000e+01   6.6900000e+01   6.3400000e+01   6.8300000e+01   7.0100000e+01   5.5000000e+01   5.5900000e+01   5.3500000e+01   5.8900000e+01   7.2100000e+01   9.8300000e+01   1.0420000e+02   1.1620000e+02   1.1040000e+02   1.1460000e+02   1.1000000e+02   1.2100000e+02   1.0870000e+02   1.0900000e+02   9.5200000e+01   8.8800000e+01   7.8300000e+01   8.3000000e+01   7.0800000e+01   8.6100000e+01   8.9500000e+01   1.0460000e+02   9.5200000e+01   1.0560000e+02   8.7400000e+01   8.5600000e+01   7.9200000e+01   8.6700000e+01   8.9800000e+01   8.2500000e+01   8.9200000e+01   9.8000000e+01   8.9900000e+01   9.7400000e+01   9.1300000e+01   1.0750000e+02   9.5700000e+01   9.3800000e+01   9.6000000e+01   1.0260000e+02   9.8400000e+01   1.0050000e+02   9.6700000e+01   1.0510000e+02   9.1700000e+01   1.0280000e+02   9.9400000e+01   3.0300000e+01   3.3300000e+01   3.3400000e+01   2.1200000e+01   2.3400000e+01   1.9400000e+01   2.6000000e+01   3.9900000e+01   6.3900000e+01   7.1000000e+01   8.0100000e+01   7.3000000e+01   7.6600000e+01   7.1500000e+01   8.5100000e+01   7.5700000e+01   7.3500000e+01   5.9000000e+01   5.1800000e+01   4.1400000e+01   4.1600000e+01   3.0800000e+01   4.8100000e+01   5.1900000e+01   6.7100000e+01   5.9600000e+01   6.9300000e+01   4.9800000e+01   5.0100000e+01   4.6000000e+01   5.0800000e+01   5.2000000e+01   4.5000000e+01   5.4300000e+01   6.4300000e+01   5.6200000e+01   6.2400000e+01   5.7500000e+01   7.1400000e+01   6.0500000e+01   6.0200000e+01   6.1400000e+01   6.5600000e+01   6.2700000e+01   6.5000000e+01   6.0000000e+01   6.6800000e+01   5.3400000e+01   6.5000000e+01   6.4400000e+01   7.9000000e+00   1.1200000e+01   1.4300000e+01   5.6000000e+00   6.8000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   8.6000000e+00   1.9300000e+01   4.1600000e+01   5.2700000e+01   6.1900000e+01   5.5300000e+01   5.2200000e+01   4.6400000e+01   6.2200000e+01   5.7400000e+01   5.5400000e+01   4.3800000e+01   3.4700000e+01   2.2600000e+01   1.8200000e+01   9.8000000e+00   3.0400000e+01   3.3700000e+01   4.9800000e+01   4.2500000e+01   5.0000000e+01   2.8800000e+01   3.0900000e+01   2.9300000e+01   2.7900000e+01   3.1000000e+01   2.3800000e+01   3.5800000e+01   4.7300000e+01   4.1400000e+01   4.2300000e+01   4.1500000e+01   5.1600000e+01   4.3600000e+01   4.2800000e+01   4.6300000e+01   4.9400000e+01   4.7700000e+01   5.3200000e+01   4.3000000e+01   4.4900000e+01   3.2700000e+01   4.3400000e+01   4.5500000e+01   1.9200000e+01   3.3600000e+01   3.3800000e+01   1.7100000e+01   1.7900000e+01   2.5200000e+01   3.1400000e+01   3.8800000e+01   5.3600000e+01   5.5800000e+01   6.4700000e+01   7.4100000e+01   7.1900000e+01   7.2700000e+01   7.7100000e+01   6.3600000e+01   6.1200000e+01   4.8100000e+01   4.0300000e+01   3.0900000e+01   3.4500000e+01   3.3300000e+01   5.2800000e+01   5.2000000e+01   6.1900000e+01   6.1600000e+01   5.6500000e+01   4.4700000e+01   4.3800000e+01   4.1500000e+01   4.4500000e+01   5.2300000e+01   4.7000000e+01   5.2700000e+01   4.7400000e+01   3.7000000e+01   4.6400000e+01   4.9800000e+01   5.9500000e+01   5.1000000e+01   5.3600000e+01   6.0600000e+01   7.2400000e+01   6.0100000e+01   5.5100000e+01   4.9400000e+01   5.6400000e+01   4.6700000e+01   5.3700000e+01   4.3400000e+01  -4.0000000e-01   1.2700000e+01   1.2000000e+01  -1.7000000e+00  -3.5000000e+00   1.5000000e+00   1.2100000e+01   2.5200000e+01   4.2500000e+01   4.4600000e+01   5.2700000e+01   5.0500000e+01   5.0000000e+01   5.1100000e+01   5.4600000e+01   5.4400000e+01   4.6600000e+01   2.9200000e+01   1.9400000e+01   6.8000000e+00   8.9000000e+00   7.2000000e+00   2.5300000e+01   3.4400000e+01   4.5700000e+01   3.9800000e+01   3.9600000e+01   2.6100000e+01   2.8500000e+01   2.6700000e+01   3.0800000e+01   3.4600000e+01   2.7600000e+01   3.8300000e+01   3.5400000e+01   2.4900000e+01   3.2300000e+01   3.0300000e+01   4.2600000e+01   3.6400000e+01   4.0100000e+01   4.3000000e+01   4.6500000e+01   4.6300000e+01   4.3600000e+01   3.6700000e+01   4.0700000e+01   3.0700000e+01   4.0600000e+01   3.3100000e+01
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are simply looking for `str2num`.

Suppose you have a cell containing two lines of numbers, stored in string format:

```
c={'0.0000000e+00   4.1800000e+01   4.4800000e+01';
'0.0000000e+00   4.1800000e+01   4.4800000e+01'}
```

Now you can get the numbers from the first line like so:

```
d=str2num(c{1})
```

---

This assumes that reading in has already been succesfull. Otherwise look into `doc dlmread`

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your answer but it worked with d=str2num(c).

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [cell2mat()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)?

That will convert your cell array to matrix of the same format as the values in the original cell array.

From the example provided by the link above:

```
c = {[1],    [2, 3, 4];
     [5; 9], [6, 7, 8; 10, 11, 12]};

m = cell2mat(c)


m =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
```

Comment: Probably this won't work as the cell does not contain numbers (instead strings representing numbers).

Comment: I might be wrong but as far as I remember, `cell2mat()` will convert any numbers represented as strings to numbers. Thus, the resulting matrix is a matrix of numbers. If the cell contained letters, then yes, it would fail.

Comment: Thanks Kkuilla for your answer but i tried it before and it didn't work.